# How to manually install IntelliJ IDEA patch update?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-14, intellij-15

I get the following connection error while updating IntelliJ behind proxy (the proxy ping in IntelliJ is working though):

Connection Error: Failed to prepare an update: Cannot download 'http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/IU-xxx-patch-win.jar': Connection closed at byte 17920. Expected 20941088 bytes. , response: 200 OK Open download page.

Solution?

I was able to download the file ...patch-win.jar via a browser.
How can I now install this patch manually for IntelliJ in a Windows environment?

Comment: **Hint:** As of now, the download URL of the patch is `https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/IU-<From>-<To>-patch-<OS>.jar`, where `<From>` is the IDEA version which you want to update, `<To>` is the target IDEA version, and `<OS>` is the type of operating system, such as `win` or `mac`. An example would be `https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/IU-181.5540.7-182.3684.101-patch-win.jar`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
java -jar IU-xxx-patch-win.jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1"
```

(replace with the actual IntelliJ IDEA installation location on your system).

Comment: Is this solustion works for android studio on linux?
I also had tried this solution, but got this error message, `no main manifest attribute, in AI-171.4474551-173.4506631-patch-unix.jar`.
By the way, here is the command I used.
`sudo java -jar AI-171.4474551-173.4506631-patch-unix.jar /opt/android-studio-preview/`
Thank you

Comment: Found the solution, a bit different with the above solutions, but works for me, at which using `-classpath` flag. Here's the snippets. 
`java -classpath PATCH_FILE_NAME com.intellij.updater.Runner install ANDROID_STUDIO_DIR`

Comment: As a caveat, notice that the path to "IntelliJ IDEA installation location" should not end in a trailing backslash, or you get an `InvalidPathException`.

Comment: on MacOS: `sudo java -jar XXXXX-patch---.jar "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/"`