# Where does android studio update patch downloaded?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I had chosen the "download update and restart" option, download complete, didn't restart, later laptop shuts down otherwise but android studio didn't get updated, and then I can't find a downloaded patch, have an option to again download it.

Comment: They are downloaded in "system" folder: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519

Comment: Did you have this experience? I want to check if I can use the previously downloaded patch to update android studio.

Comment: it should be possible if full JAR was downloaded: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364476/how-to-manually-install-intellij-idea-patch-update

Answer (score 0):

It will be downloaded in a `path` like this:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2023.1\tmp\patch-update
```

There is a `.jar` file there. You can install it using:

```
java -jar "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio***\tmp\patch-update\AI-***-patch-win.jar" install "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
```

**Note 1:** You should provide your own IDE's path based on the version instead of `AndroidStudio2023.1` in this example.

**Note 2:** If you are getting some errors that files are `locked by JDK Platform`, try to `kill the process` using `TaskManager` and then run the update again.

**Note 3:** If you receive `access denied` error while updating, try to run `cmd` in `administrator` mode and run the command.